# How to convert plain text to html hyperlink in java?

Tags: java

I am using the current expression to convert plain text hyperlink like with http or https to html hyperlinks

```
String pattern = "(?:https|http)://([^\\s\\|]+)";
```

However in the message content that will go through this regular expression pattern i have content like `[video]http://www.yahoo.com[video].`

For this kind of content in between the two video brackets. I do not want it to be converted to html hyperlink because it will be displayed on the page.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Huh?  1st you ask *"How to convert plain text to html hyperlink in java?"* Then you mention you've already done it *"I am using the current expression to convert plain text .. to html hyperlinks"* then you add *"I do not want it to be converted to html hyperlink"*  All that adds up to nothing that makes sense in my head.  Can you explain in different words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negative lookahead and lookbehind using `(?<!...)` and `(?!...)`:

```
String link = "(?:https|http)://([^\\s\\|]+)";
String pattern = "(?<!\\[video\\])" + link + "(?!\\[video\\])";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
System.out.println(p.matcher("[video]http://www.yahoo.com[video]").matches());
System.out.println(p.matcher("http://www.yahoo.com").matches());
```

Outputs:

```
false
true
```

---

### Full example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
            "(?<!\\[video\\])(?:https|http)://([^\\s\\|]+)(?!\\[video\\])");

    String text = "This is some example text with a link" +
        "[video]http://videolink[video] that should not be replaced" + 
        "and another link that should be" +
        "replaced http://www.example.com";

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find())
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "<a href=\""+m.group()+"\">"+m.group() +"</a>");
    m.appendTail(sb);

    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Outputs:

> This is some example text with a link
>   [video]http://videolink[video] that should not be replaced
>   and another link that should be
>   replaced http://www.example.com

Comment: What does negative lookahead and lookbehind means exactly?

Comment: Check out the [regex tutorial - lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: You do not want to match links between `[video]` so we check that the link doesn't start or end with that. That is what negative lookahead and negative lookbehind is all about.